# How to create a Junction Point using WinApi?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, junction

There is `CreateHardLink` function to create Hardlinks.(Since Win2000)
And there is `CreateSymbolicLink` function since Vista has been released.

But why isn't there a `CreateJunction`?

How does `mklink` make a junction?
And How do I write codes to make junction in my app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're reparse points, so FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT is the magic FSCTL. Here's an example, never tried it but seems right:

http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/hard-links.phtml

-scott

Comment: @efotinis where did you get this info from? Documentation has no mention of this.

Comment: @teivaz, I don't know why I wrote that... My mistake.

Answer (score 6):

There's currently no built-in single function for creating junctions like there is for symbolic links or hard links. Like snoone said, it's a reparse point, so you have to use [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to interact with it. If I remember correctly, the source he linked is the same source I played around with when I was trying to figure this out, and I don't think I ran into any issues with it.

Alternatively, if you're not against using an external library in your application, and you're going to need functionality for reading/checking/deleting junctions, you might want to look into [reparselib](https://github.com/amdf/reparselib), which is a pretty decent library wrapping junctions, symbolic links, mount points, and custom reparse points.